# Struggling to sort an array of structs using an array of pointers. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

So I'm trying to sort an array of structs by using an array of pointers. I'm trying to sort the struct based on the `int score` member of the `Test` struct. I'm getting a bunch of errors and I think they are all related to something specific that I am doing wrong. (Or I just clearly don't have the slightest conceptual grasp about how this all works.)

Here are the errors:
[Screenshot of List of Errors](http://postimg.org/image/lbqufdw7l/d3a845e7/)

And here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>   


using namespace std; 

struct Test;
void selectionSort(int num, struct Test* sortArray[]);


int main()
{
    const int NO_ERRRORS = 0;

    int num, scoreIn;
    string nameIn;


    cout << "Please provide the number of test scores you would " << endl
        << "like to average and sort." << endl << endl
        << "Please limit your request to 5-20 tests: ";
    cin >> num;
    while ((num < 5) || (num > 20))
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter an integer between 5-20: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    cout << endl;

    Test* tests = new Test[num];

    Test** sortArray = new Test*[num];

    cout << "Please enter first names only with no spaces." << endl << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < num; index++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the name of student " << (index + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> nameIn;
        cout << "Enter the test score: ";
        cin >> scoreIn;
        while (scoreIn < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter a positive integer: ";
            cin >> scoreIn;
        }
        cout << endl;

        ((*(tests + index)) = { nameIn, scoreIn }); //IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches operands. Operand types are Test = {..}  
        sortArray[index] = &tests[index];
    }

    selectionSort(num, sortArray);

    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
         cout << (sortArray[count]->score) << " ";
    cout << endl;


    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
        cout << (sortArray[count]->name) << " ";
    cout << endl;


    delete[] tests;


    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail(), '\n');
    cout << endl << "Press only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();

    return NO_ERRRORS;

}

void selectionSort(int num, struct Test* sortArray[])
{


    int minIndex;
    Test *minElem;
    for (int scan = 0; scan < (num - 1); scan++)
    {
        minIndex = scan;
        minElem = sortArray[scan];
        for (int index = scan + 1; index < num; index++)
        {
            if ((*(sortArray[index])) < (*minElem)) //IntelliSense: no operator "<" matches operands. Operand types are Test < Test 
            {
                minElem = sortArray[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        sortArray[minIndex] = sortArray[scan];
        sortArray[scan] = minElem;
    }
}

struct Test
{
    int num = num;

     Test()
    {
            name = "";
            score = 0;
    }
    string name;
    int score;
};
```

Obviously I'm not asking anyone to do my work for me. But could someone maybe point me in the right direction...conceptually? Maybe point out where I go wrong first and cause the cascade of errors?

Any help very much appreciated.

Edit: I messed up and forgot to mention the constraints I am working in. 
1. Must use a selection sort.

Comment: `int num = num;` what is this ? You can just sort this one `Test* tests = new Test[num];` instead of having `sortArray`. Try changing the `selectionSort()` to `void selectionSort(int num, Test* tests)` and then work on your sort logic with that.

Comment: What's your compiler and working environment ? If you have c++11 compliant compiler then @Lightness Races in Orbit 's answer is the way to handle objects in container and sort them.

Comment: @Jagannath: My idea behind using the `sortArray` was to protect the original array from any possible access/ changes. But you're right. Omitting it would probably be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting a container of objects by members of those objects is much easier than this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Test
{
    Test()
       : score(0)
       , num(0)
    {}

    std::string name;
    int score;
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    const unsigned int num = 5;  // user input in your case
    std::vector<Test> v(num);

    //!! Assign values to items in `v`

    std::sort(
       v.begin(),
       v.end(),
       [](const Test& lhs, const Test& rhs) {
          return lhs.num < rhs.num;
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here : OP is doing school work => his professor wants him to implement selection sort. +1 anyway. it's good reference material.

Comment: @FélixCantournet: If the OP has constraints then he should state them, clearly, in the question.

Comment: @FélixCantournet: Yeah, I messed up and forgot to mention that I need to use the selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

the fact that there is struct with just 1 integer does not makes it an integer , it's still a struct. in order to compare objects (which in fact , what a struct produces) you need to overload the comparison operator , and in your case > operator.